# How to skip over .lastModified() files that contain a String, and select the next .lastModified() file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, do-while

Ok, so I am currently trying to select the most recent file in a directory (/FSTP/LOGS in this example), but I want to ignore any files that contain the String "DEBUG - null", but NOT the String "DEBUG - MA" or "INFO - MA".  Those search terms are instantiated through sTechNull, sTechValid, and sTechValidInfo, respectively.

I want to skip over files that I consider null by my parameters (Must have the 'MA' aspect in the file, to report accurately), and go to the next file that does contain the data I'm looking for here in Scanner.

I have tried a do-while loop, but I don't seem to have it correct.  I am also unsure if I should check for these Strings and decrement the File lastModifiedFile to get to the file I need containing non-null data.

I am aware my code below is incorrect.  I am just missing what I'm doing wrong.  To clarify, when this method fires, it will set the most recent, non-null File to be read by a Scanner in another method.  If the lastModified() method returns a file that contains data I do not want, I want to skip that file, and select the next file to be read for non-null data, and so forth.  Once the code reaches an acceptable File to pass to the separate method, it will stop and not run until the next call of the recentLog() method.

Hope I made this clear!

How should I be skipping the files I consider null?

```
private static void recentLog() {
    File dir = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FSTP/LOGS/"));
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    {
        if (files.length == 0) return;
        File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
        Boolean checkNull = null;
        do {
            for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
                if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified())
                    lastModifiedFile = files[i];
                try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(lastModifiedFile)) {
                    String sTechNull = "DEBUG - null";
                    String sTechValid = "DEBUG - MA";
                    String s1Check = scanner.next();
                    while (scanner.hasNextLine() && !s1Check.equals("exit")) {
                        String line = scanner.nextLine();
                        if (s1Check.equals(R.string.exit)) scanner.close();
                        if (line.contains(sTechNull) && !line.contains(sTechValid)) {
                           checkNull = true;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }while(checkNull);
        lMod = lastModifiedFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

---

---

EDIT: I found my solution, and most of you were correct, I was not clear enough.  I tried to implement @flup's solution using the comparator and a separate validation method.  I found this cumbersome for what I was trying to accomplish, due to further research into the log files I was going to be reading.  There were some files that contained all the strings I was looking for above, so I decided it was best to just filter the logging method I created in my package to write to an xml file.

I want to apologize for being unclear, but seeing my solution take form helped me understand how to better word my questions, as well as how to decide which set up would produce the behavior I'm looking for.  I ended up deciding to read the most recent file, regardless of content, and just checking in my logging script if the data is valid according to conditions set below:

```
 public static File recentLog() {
    File dir = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FSTP/LOGS/"));
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    {
        if (files.length == 0) return null;
        File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified())
                lastModifiedFile = files[i];
        }
        lMod = lastModifiedFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The above method selects the most recent file.

```
if (line.contains("DEBUG - null") && !(line.contains("DEBUG - MA") || line.contains("INFO - MA"))) {
                foundTech = null;
                dateLogged = null;
}
```

The above snipped I have inserted into my first scanner method that I was going to pass my "valid" file into, but I felt that using a scanner twice was a bit redundant, so I instead used a filter by looking for when my log file did not contain any "DEBUG - MA" or "INFO - MA" strings but did include "DEBUG - null", and assigned my desired values to null.

```
public static string runLogger() throws IOException{
final String fTech = foundTech;
if (fTech != null) {
        log.delete();
        log.createNewFile();
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {.....
        .......
}
```

I then set my xml logging method to ignore the code and simply not execute the xml logging code if the foundTech variable was null.  This provided the behavior I wanted, as I did not want to update the .xml file if there was no new valid data.  What I was describing would have read backwards in my file list until it found valid data, and reported it each time.  I find that method would have been more difficult to maintain than a simple conditional statement in the logging method.  My file .lastModified() method was already working fine for me as I had it, so I decided to attempt to filter out the bad files ahead of time.  Thinking my solution through made me realize I did want to read the most recent file and pass that variable to my runLogger() method, so I will close this question.

Sorry for the confusion of this all, I'm just a newbie navigating the waters for the first time.  On the upside, I just completed my first Java/Android project at work, and I'm moving into the testing phase now that everything is functioning properly!  Thanks for the guidance StackO!

Comment: If you want an answer, I suggest you ask a specific question.

Comment: have you seen that there's a method `listFiles` that accepts a `FileNameFilter`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FilenameFilter)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Updated the post. What i need to know is how to adjust my code to ignore the File lastModifiedFile that my .lastModified() method returns, if it does not contain the data I need, and then go to the next .lastModified(), and again until i have an acceptable file.

Comment: @Joe I suggest sorting the files in reverse order of last modified and stop as soon as you get an acceptable file.

Comment: @flup I need to read inside the file to determine if it is "not null". The file names themselves will all begin with FSTP_*_*_*, so the filter wouldn't help, would it? I need to check if the Strings "DEBUG - MA" or "INFO - MA" exist in the file before I pass the lastModifiedFile.getAbsolutePath() method to lMod. If those two stings are not in the file, then go to the next most recent file.

Comment: So do that. What's the question?

Comment: My question I suppose was if I should be doing this in the same method with a do-while loop like I tried above, or if there was a more efficient way to set it up.  I am learning Java/Android for work, and have developed this project from the ground up with no previous programming experience.  I am getting more acquainted with StackEx, and I'm getting better at navigating existing threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split off the content filter code to a separate method:

```
private static boolean accept(File file)
{
    // this is what I gather from your description
    boolean containsNull = false;
    boolean containsMA = false;
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file))
    {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            final String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (line.contains("DEBUG - null"))
            {
                containsNull = true;
            }
            if (line.contains("DEBUG - MA") || line.contains("INFO - MA"))
            {
                containsMA = true;
            }
        }
        return containsMA || !containsNull;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then to determine the most recent file that is acceptable, first sort the files and then feed them to the filter method one by one, stopping as soon as you find the first match:

```
private static File recentLog(File directory)
{
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    // sort
    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(File f1, File f2)
        {
            // reverse comparison, looking for the highest value of lastModified
            return -Long.compare(f1.lastModified(), f2.lastModified());
        }
    });
    // find first acceptable file
    for (File file : files)
    {
        if (accept(file))
        {
            return file;
        }
    }
    // no acceptable files found
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I updated my original post to clarify what I was asking and how I came to my solution.  What you have written here does actually come pretty close to doing what I described originally, but unfortunately I failed in providing enough context to communicate what I was trying to do.  I'll give you the answer, because you did answer my poorly worded question correctly!